# DCF77 time signal emulator by Raspberry Pi Zero WH

Tags: gpio, pi-zero-w

This is my first post on this forum.
Thanks for being welcomed into this community.
I am struggling with my second project with a RaspberryPi.
On Github I found a very interesting project of an emulator of a 77.5 KHz DCF77 signal that uses a Zero WH and a simple copper coil as an antenna (https://github.com/hzeller/txtempus).
Where I live, in central Italy, the sign of the German atomic clock arrives so weak that it cannot enter the house, so my three DCF77 clocks and the weather station can almost never synchronize automatically..
This thing is obviously very depressing.
The range of the signal generated by the original system is very limited, so much so that it is necessary to "immerse" the clock to be synchronized with the coil / antenna.
So I would like to modify it by adding a small power amplifier with which to feed a ferrite rod antenna.
 This is to extend the signal range to about ten meters.
The ferrite antenna is built to resonate at the frequency of 77.5 KHz, presenting a resistive load of about 5.75 ohms.
As an amplifier I am using an LM386 module, very inexpensive and very simple to use, calibrated to deliver a maximum power of 100 mW on the load (the ferrite antenna).
Unfortunately I can't understand why between the GPIO4 and GPIO17 and the circuit ground the 3 resistors in the figure were put, with those values.
Is this a voltage divider? Or what else? By what criterion do you think those values were chosen?
I searched the net for an answer without finding it. Can you help me understand?
Thank you very much.
[image]

Comment: Though not a solution, you may find the Man With A Swiss Accent’s (Andreas Spiess) recent video of some help https://youtu.be/6SHGAEhnsYk

Comment: Yes, the Swiss guy's YT is very good. The answer starts around 10 min. https://imgur.com/gallery/CzLlMdy. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you very much for the link and the circuit schema.

Comment: Hi @mvittorini, you are welcome. Just now I tried to install the clock time signal program, but sadly got the error message: "Frequency generation is known ***NOT WORKING FOR Rpi4***; Use older Rpi's for now, ..." :(